# hostname not found through VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, network-manager, vpn

I set up a VPN using my FritzBox 7530. I have Machine A connected to this router and Machine B outside the network.
Once the VPN is active I get a DHCP address for Machine B in the same subnet of Machine A, and this is great.

I can access via SSH from both machines, using SFTP and so on. The only drawback is I have to use the IP address. The hostname is not recognized from both ends.

Instead, if both machines are physically inside the same LAN (connected to the FritzBox) I can ping, SSH, SMB, etc... using their hostnames.

**Is there anything further to set up in either FritzBox or machines in order to enable the hostname resolution through VPN?**

Both machines runs Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I am confused as to what your VPN is supposed to do for you.

Comment: I have a client outside my network (i.e. in a different house) and I want to connect it to my LAN and see it as it is inside my LAN.

Comment: OK I have no issue with that but that is not a VPN. You would need to have some kind of server to do this unless you can run a physical cable to the other house.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Why it's not a VPN? My connection is actually a VPN. The server is FritzBox and the client my laptop with network manager. I filled in the VPN configuration and I'm able to connect it. From my LAN I can see the laptop as it was inside the LAN itself.

Comment: You subscribe to a commercial VPN service? The fritzbox is a modem/router not a server. I suggest you do a LOT of research as you certainly seem confused as to what a VPN and a server are.

Comment: I don't want to be rude but I use VPN since several years to connect my devices to my own LAN when I'm, say, at customer's place. I always used my FritzBox to create the VPN connection (yes, it can: https://en.avm.de/service/vpn/tips-tricks/setting-up-a-vpn-connection-to-fritzbox-in-linux/).